# Beyond Compare:How to compare specific sql files?

Tags: sql, compare

I need to compare two *.sql files which have serval changes. There are some changes like date and time which should be ignored. BC shows differences when just the time changes like:

**File one:** 13.06.14, 10:42   **Files two:** 13.06.14, 10:43.

How can i script it that BC ignores the date and time when comparing the two files?

Comment: Where are these data time from? Are they part of business logic or generated by tools?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help, you can find an explanation hire:

[Define Unimportant Text in Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3)

There is also a very useful video explaining the steps to define unimportant text in Beyond Compare on that link.